# Safari LastTab plugin Mac OS X

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extensions

I'm looking for Safari plugin that allow tab navigation in recently-used-order manner.
Exactly like LastTab Firefox plugin do.

Is there any possible ways to do this on Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Glims](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims):

> Glims adds a cocktail of features to Safari (Tabs, Thumbnails, Full Screen, Search Engines, Search Suggestions, Forms autocomplete on, Dated download folders, Type Ahead ...)
>
> Current features list:
>
> - ...
> - Focus last selected tab
> - ...

Comment: Installed. Checked "Focus last selected tab" option. Nothing happens ;(